# Let $k =\mathbb{Z}_2$, study the ring of polynomial on this field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k = \mathbb{Z}_2$, I want to answer the following questions:

1) Write the four polynomials of degree $2$ in $k[x]$. Are they irreducible?

2) Let $I$ be the ideal of $k[x]$ generated by $x^4 + x +1$; is $I$ maximal?

3) Consider $L = k[x]/I$. Which are the multiplicative orders of the non zero elements of $L$?

4) Let $\alpha \in L$ be the class of $x$: verify that $\alpha^2 + \alpha$ is invertible in $L$ and calculate its inverse.

This is what I managed to do:

1) The four polynomials are: $x^2$, $x^2 + x + 1$, $x^2 + 1$, $x^2 + x$.

$x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible, while $x^2$, $x^2 +1$ and $x^2 + x$ are reducible.

2) I recall from theory that an ideal is maximal if $k[x]/I$ is a field. This object is a field if the polynomial that generates the ideal is irreducible. This is the case so $I$ is maximal.

3) Here I'm stuck. I can't understand the structure of $L$.

Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Oooops, dumb mistake, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 3** $L$ is the finite field $\mathbb F_{2^4}$ with $16$ elements. In that field, the group of non-zero elements is the cyclic group of order $15$. Hence the multiplicative orders of the non zero elements of $\mathbb F_{2^4}$ belong to $\{1,3, 5, 15\}$.

**Question 4** To prove that $\alpha^2 +\alpha$ is invertible where $\alpha \in L$ is in the class of $x$, it is sufficient to prove that $x^4 + x +1$ and $x^2+x$ are coprime in $k[x]$. For this you can use [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the **gcd** of those two polynomials. You have 
$$\begin{aligned}
x^4+x + 1 &= (x^2+x+1)(x^2+x)+1
\end{aligned}$$

By hypothesis, you have $\alpha^4+\alpha+1 =0$, hence $(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha)=1$. Which proves that the inverse of $\alpha^2+\alpha$ is $\alpha^2+\alpha+1$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. Why are there 16 elements? Where does the cyclic group come from? Could you expand on question 4) as well?

Comment: $L$ is a field of characteristic $2$. Its degree on $\mathbb Z_2$ is equal to $4$ as $p(x)=x^4+x+1$ is irreducible of degree $4$. Hence $L$ has $2^4=16$ elements. Now this is a theorem that the non zero elements of a field is a multiplicative cyclic group (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Multiplicative_structure). As you have $16-1$ non zero elements, the non zero elements form a cyclic group of order $15$. In that group, the order of the elements can only be $1,3,5,15$ (the divisors of $15$).

Comment: Let's see if I can come up with something for 4) now. $\alpha^2 + \alpha$ is invertibile if $x^2 + x$ is coprime with $x^4 + x + 1$, this is the case, so I just need to find the inverse. Let u($\alpha$) be the inverse, by Bezout theorem there exists $v(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $u*(\alpha^2 + \alpha) + v*(x^4 + x + 1) = 1$, but I am struggling to find such v.

Comment: @LudovicoBessi See the new version of my answer where I describe how to compute the inverse.